# Lookup release date for any given Windows Update with Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi-query

We have SCCM 2012 R2 installed in our environment, I can execute a WMI query to get information about patches on a given computer like this:

```
$updates = Get-WmiObject -Class CCM_UpdateStatus -Namespace ROOT\ccm\SoftwareUpdates\UpdatesStore -ComputerName $Computer
```

This gives me all kinds of information about the patches including the Article, Bulletin, Installed Status, Patch Title, Product ID, etc. One of the missing items is when the patch was issued or released by Microsoft. Is there a query I can make with the information I have about the patch to get the release date from some other source?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the SCCM Application database, you can query the dbo.v_UpdateInfo view.

This has a handy column called "DatePosted" which will tell you when an update was released by MS.

I don't believe that the information is stored on client machines - Also, if you want (As it looks like you are handy with PowerShell) try out PSWindowsUpdate:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc

Bear in mind that the Get-WUList queries the SoftwareDistribution folder on the client machine (which is what your query does as well I believe) so if that folder is deleted, it will return nothing.

HTH